# Drag drop not working in iOS when using MasterDetailsPage to display custom ListView using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, drag-and-drop, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a custom control and an iOS custom renderer for ordering list items by drag and drop (inheriting from ListView and ListViewRenderer). I have placed the control on a very simple page.

Dragging the items in the OrderListView works without a hitch when I set the page directly to the the application's MainPage. It also works when the page is pushed to a NavigationPage.

However, as soon as I use a MasterDetailsPage the drag operation does not work. The drag operation ends as soon as I start dragging, resulting in the item's new location beeing the same as the old.

Anyone got an idea on why the custom control behaves differently when used in MasterDetailsPage? I'm just guessing but maybe the MasterDetailsPage has some built in gestures that conflicts with the ListView's?

### Application startup:

**Working:**

```
public App()
{
    MainPage = new OrderListPage();
}
```

**Not working:**

```
public App()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     var masterDetailsPage = new MasterDetailPage
         {
            Master = new MenuPage(),
            Detail = new OrderListPage()
        };

     MainPage = masterDetailsPage;
}
```